# Having Listeners in Service or IntentService?

Tags: android

I am designing a chat application with xmpp, in order to replace my `AsyncTask` with a better solution (which doesnt memory leak, configuration changes have no effect, manages job queue's, running more than just 1 `AsyncTask` at moment, etc).

There I came up with a solution: `IntentService`. At first every thing look too good for it which makes you doubt about its too good being, at moment, my `AsyncTask`s live in a service that will run for days,and their job is to do Network sending & receiving.

So now in another service I have Listeners, which listen for packets, I'm wondering is `IntentService` a good Idea for using as a Listener service (since I have seen `IntentService` works with `Intent`s, so i wondered may be it does some jobs upon requests), or i should keep it up with basic Service?

Also I'm wondering: Why use `AsyncTask` when there is `IntentService`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> there i came up with a solution : IntentService

An `IntentService` is not designed for your scenario. It is designed to do a bit of work on a background thread, then go away.

> i should keep it up with basic Service?

Yes, though an `AsyncTask` is probably not needed in the service, as you normally do not want to be doing anything on the main application thread in a service. Just use a `Thread` or `ThreadPoolExecutor` in the service.

> Also im wondering Why use AsyncTask when there is IntentService?

Among other reasons, `AsyncTask` can use a thread pool; an `IntentService` has only one background thread.

Comment: my scenario is doing abit of network jobs once every moment :) and just 1 AsyncTask can be run at the moment, right?they are serialled, and IntentService has built in Jobqeue which is fine for me with a little trick ;)

Comment: @user3764748: "and just 1 AsyncTask can be run at the moment, right?they are serialled" -- not if you use `executeOnExecutor()`.

Comment: not sure if thats true, i 've heared alot that its a serious problem of AsyncTask thats just 1 can be ran at a time

Comment: @user3764748: Talented programmers read [the documentation for `AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), particularly the section on "Order of execution".